# Networking drops all the time - fixed with network-manager restart

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, aspire

I'm having a very strange problem.

I have an aspire v nitro laptop running Ubuntu 18 which dual boots to windows and suddenly yesterday the internet kept cutting out. This can be fixed by restarting the network-manager.

If I try and ping anything when it isn't working I get

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e09d]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

and `iwconfig`

```
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Bluffin Muff McGuff"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: 54:67:51:DA:AF:BF   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:73   Missed beacon:0
```

I've done a lot of googling and found lots of answers that don't help. I've even reinstalled the entire OS (after fucking up my networking completely trying to fix it).

Any ideas anyone?

edit: - the commands i was told to enter

```
nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION          
wlp6s0  wifi      connected    Bluffin Muff McGuff 
enp7s0  ethernet  unavailable  --                  
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

```
sudo lshw -short -class network
H/W path       Device     Class          Description
====================================================
/0/100/1c/0    wlp6s0     network        QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapt
/0/100/1c.3/0  enp7s0     network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit E
```

```
networkctl status
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

●        State: n/a
       Address: 192.168.0.52 on wlp6s0
                2a02:8388:7001:5d80:4540:4576:28fd:3b58 on wlp6s0
                2a02:8388:7001:5d80:754b:c96c:dc20:7b43 on wlp6s0
                fe80::5e90:7e4e:7688:acea on wlp6s0
       Gateway: 192.168.0.1 (Compal Broadband Networks, Inc.) on wlp6s0
                fe80::5667:51ff:fedb:ac25 (Compal Broadband Networks, Inc.) on 
        State: n/a
       Address: 192.168.0.52 on wlp6s0
                2a02:8388:7001:5d80:4540:4576:28fd:3b58 on wlp6s0
                2a02:8388:7001:5d80:754b:c96c:dc20:7b43 on wlp6s0
                fe80::5e90:7e4e:7688:acea on wlp6s0
       Gateway: 192.168.0.1 (Compal Broadband Networks, Inc.) on wlp6s0
                fe80::5667:51ff:fedb:ac25 (Compal Broadband Networks, Inc.) on
```

```
rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE             SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      acer-wireless unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0          unblocked unblocked
 4 bluetooth hci0            blocked unblocked
```

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 25 23:10 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

edit2:

Okay firstly I had `ping 8.8.8.8` running in the background while it went off.

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=566 ttl=122 time=18.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=567 ttl=122 time=20.3 ms
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
```

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 32
       serial: 18:4f:32:b5:ca:cb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.18.0-18-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.0.52 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 memory:94000000-941fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 15
       serial: 30:65:ec:8a:a0:cd
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94204000-94204fff memory:94200000-94203fff
```

```
dmesg | grep -i wlp6s0 
[   15.392889] ath10k_pci 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
[   33.459583] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[   34.197278] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[   34.898963] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[   39.792930] wlp6s0: authenticate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf
[   39.847542] wlp6s0: send auth to 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[   39.868316] wlp6s0: authenticated
[   39.872106] wlp6s0: associate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[   39.913957] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[   39.917295] wlp6s0: associated
[   40.621555] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
[ 5772.041721] wlp6s0: deauthenticating from 54:67:51:da:af:bf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 5777.593015] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 5778.358382] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 5778.471103] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 5783.388233] wlp6s0: authenticate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf
[ 5783.444693] wlp6s0: send auth to 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 5783.465210] wlp6s0: authenticated
[ 5783.466775] wlp6s0: associate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 5783.508253] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[ 5783.511065] wlp6s0: associated
[ 5783.540761] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
[ 6169.007742] wlp6s0: deauthenticating from 54:67:51:da:af:bf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 6174.676947] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 6175.444728] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 6175.559420] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 6180.450842] wlp6s0: authenticate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf
[ 6180.505205] wlp6s0: send auth to 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 6180.525923] wlp6s0: authenticated
[ 6180.530653] wlp6s0: associate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 6180.573152] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[ 6180.576150] wlp6s0: associated
[ 6180.604972] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
[ 6507.292646] wlp6s0: deauthenticating from 54:67:51:da:af:bf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 6512.947438] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 6513.710596] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 6513.817718] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 6518.723552] wlp6s0: authenticate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf
[ 6518.777723] wlp6s0: send auth to 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 6518.798235] wlp6s0: authenticated
[ 6518.798570] wlp6s0: associate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 6518.839995] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[ 6518.842529] wlp6s0: associated
[ 6518.872491] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
[ 7213.465121] wlp6s0: deauthenticated from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (Reason: 4=DISASSOC_DUE_TO_INACTIVITY)
[ 7213.513877] wlp6s0: authenticate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf
[ 7213.564154] wlp6s0: send auth to 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 7213.584967] wlp6s0: authenticated
[ 7213.588965] wlp6s0: associate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 7213.631522] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[ 7213.634487] wlp6s0: associated
[ 7369.018698] wlp6s0: deauthenticating from 54:67:51:da:af:bf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 7369.464133] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 7370.223353] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 7370.326891] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 7375.221841] wlp6s0: authenticate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf
[ 7375.275592] wlp6s0: send auth to 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 7375.296914] wlp6s0: authenticated
[ 7375.300681] wlp6s0: associate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 7375.343005] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[ 7375.346102] wlp6s0: associated
[ 7375.375993] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
[ 7753.050810] wlp6s0: deauthenticating from 54:67:51:da:af:bf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 7758.505647] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 7759.259469] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 7759.381181] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 7764.284278] wlp6s0: authenticate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf
[ 7764.338257] wlp6s0: send auth to 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 7764.360011] wlp6s0: authenticated
[ 7764.361525] wlp6s0: associate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 7764.404107] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[ 7764.407021] wlp6s0: associated
[ 7764.436045] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
[ 8675.862443] wlp6s0: deauthenticated from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (Reason: 4=DISASSOC_DUE_TO_INACTIVITY)
[ 8676.102072] wlp6s0: authenticate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf
[ 8676.152726] wlp6s0: send auth to 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 8676.174711] wlp6s0: authenticated
[ 8676.178618] wlp6s0: associate with 54:67:51:da:af:bf (try 1/3)
[ 8676.220993] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 54:67:51:da:af:bf (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[ 8676.224142] wlp6s0: associated
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `nmcli device`, 2. `sudo lshw -short -class network`, 3. `networkctl status` and  4. `rfkill`, 5. `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Please issue this command `sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`. **Reboot** your system.  Now test your Wi-Fi by connecting to internet and see it is `stable`.

Comment: okay just done that and it seems to have been working now for the past 30+ minutes

you're a lifesaver!! thank you very much!

Comment: I spoke too soon. It has not fixed my problem.

Comment: Can you explain what happened? Was it unstable? Or too slow?

Comment: It just works perfectly then after X amount of time (from 1 minute to 30) seems to stop.

Comment: Please post the output of the two commands: `sudo lshw -C network | grep -i  -A12 "Wireless interface"` and `dmesg | grep -i wlp6s0`

Comment: added the extra info :D